# extracting data from a SpGridView selected row

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, wss-3.0

Using [SPGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spgridview.aspx), I want to fill textboxes with the SPGridview Selected Row Data on a button click event.

```
txtCode= SPGridView.SelectedRow.Cell[1].Text;
```

On debugging, it shows `Cell[1]` is empty but it is showing data in the Grid.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that cell index start at 0.

you can also try this

```
((TextBox)SPGridView.Rows[SPGridView.SlectedIndex].Cells[1].Controls[0]).Text;
```

Answer (score 2):

I've just got similar problem.
And I've find out that "selectedvalue" is solution.
so try :

```
txtCode.Text = Convert.ToString(oSPGridView.SelectedValue);
```